# tkFileDialog.askopenfilename() appears broken on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, tkinter

When I run

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog
root = Tk()
root.filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
```

Then a window comes up but it not usable. When the cursor is over the window it turns into the loading cursor but nothing loads.

[image]

I expect to be able to select a file.

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 in VirtualBox and Python 2.7.14

Comment: I can't duplicate your results, though I'm not on Ubuntu 17.10. Have you tries starting `mainloop` and then popping up the dialog using `after` or `after_idle`?

Comment: This code worked fine for me on Ubuntu MATE 17.10 with Python 2.7.14; the file open dialog was normal

Comment: @duckmayr Could it be a GNOME issue then? How difficult is it to switch to MATE?

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if it could possibly be a GNOME issue, which is why I mentioned I was on Ubuntu MATE. I originally used vanilla Ubuntu, then later switched to Ubuntu MATE for my laptop. I found the switch really easy, but of course your experience may vary. Frankly I've found I prefer MATE to both GNOME and Unity, but that's me. Ultimately I don't know if that will help you -- if you're writing something for others to use, you may need it to work on vanilla Ubuntu anyway.